# Deleting a specific row on multiple worksheets using a userform

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, userform

I am developing a tool to track pupil assessments and am using a userform to manage pupil data.

I have written code based on responses to previous questions to delete the same row on 14 worksheets within the workbook which contain various pupil data but am getting an 'Object required' error at the `WshtNameCrnt.Rows(l).Delete` line in the code below:

```
Private Sub cmbDelete_Click()
    Dim WshtNames As Variant
    Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant

    WshtNames = Array("Pupil Data", "RWM", "Art", "Computing", "Design Technology", "Geography", "History_", _
                        "MFL", "Music", "PE", "RE", "Science", "Bookbands", "KS1 - TRP")

    Dim msgResponse As String    'confirm delete
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            msgResponse = MsgBox("This will delete the selected record. Continue?", _
            vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Delete Entry")

    Select Case msgResponse    'action dependent on response

        Case vbYes
            Dim l As Long
            l = ActiveCell.Row 'store currently active cell row

                For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames
                    WshtNameCrnt.Rows(l).Delete
                Next

        'restore form settings
        With Me
            .cmbAmend.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
            .cmbDelete.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
            .cmbAdd.Enabled = True    'restore use
            'clear form
            Call ClearControls
            Call ResortData
        End With

    Case vbNo
        Exit Sub    'cancelled
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I assume that the issue is that my array of worksheet names is dimensioned as a variant but am not sure of the best way to set this as an object and to loop through the worksheets in the array.

Please can someone advise me if my assumption is correct and suggest/show me how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WshtNameCrnt` is the name of the `Worksheet`, not the actual `Worksheet` object.

So instead of

```
WshtNameCrnt.Rows(l).Delete
```

use the [`Worksheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets) collection, which works with either the `Worksheet` index or *name*, to return the `Worksheet` object in question.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WshtNameCrnt).Rows(1).Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

@BigBen found out the issue and a possible solution

another solution would be iterating through a `Worksheets` collection whose names you collected in `WshtNames` array

```
            For Each WshtNameCrnt In Worksheets(WshtNames)
                WshtNameCrnt.Rows(l).Delete
            Next
```

both solutions (and your code) suffer from not managing the case of a sheet name not matching any of current workbook worksheets ones

Comment: Thank you for the additional answer and picking up on the issue of sheet names not matching those in the current workbook ones. This isn't going to become an issue as the sheets and sheet names will be static once I have the system set up and finalised.